# getting columns of pandas series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I exported some data of a pandas dataframe with the frequencies (I will do a pie chart after) with the "value_counts()" function. I then get a pandas series. How can I access the both columns of df (in the right colum are my frequencies, in the left one the labels)?

```
df=data.loc[data['Kanton'] == 'AG', 'Kat'].value_counts()
df
```

I tried df.to_frame() to access the columns but it is still a series.....

[image: code]

Comment: What do you mean?  What are you expecting as an output?  You have both the index and the data, right?

Comment: Note that `df.to_frame()` *returns* the series as a dataframe. It does not change the series into a dataframe. To do that, you would need to do `df = df.to_frame()`. But you do not need to convert a Series into a dataframe.

Comment: You can access the data column of a Series with `list(series)` or the index column with `series.index`. Or there are many other ways to access the data. E.g. `df.loc[6]` will look up the element with index 6 and give you 2.